# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou iniciando com o entity seguindo este [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Meu método está dando erro na função no momento do SaveChanges();

Meu Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmpresaController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly CrudContext _context;

    public EmpresaController(CrudContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        if(_context.Empresas.Count() == 0)
        {
            _context.Empresas.Add(new Empresa { Nome = "Empresa", Cep = "14620-000"});
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }

    //GET: api/empresa
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Empresa>>> getEmpresas()
    {
        return await _context.Empresas.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Minha classe Empresa:

```
{
    public class Empresa
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Complemento { get; set; }
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Localidade { get; set; }
        public string UF { get; set; }
        public string Unidade { get; set; }
        public int IBGE { get; set; }
        public int GIA { get; set; }
    }
```

Quando bato na api/empresa eu recebo:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to
>   type 'System.Int64

Comment: No banco de dados, qual é o tipo da coluna?

Comment: E em qual propriedade você está encontrando o erro?